# How do you formally express transforming the dual space of a vector space into the original space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a vector space $V$ there always exists a dual space $V^*$ made by all the linear functions that map a member of $V$ onto $F$ where $F$ is the underlying scalar field.

In finite dimensional vector spaces over the reals, the dual space is represented through the concept of row and column vectors.

This means that the transpostion function is actually a way to travel between the base base and its dual, i.e. $V \rightarrow V^T$ and $V^T \rightarrow V$.

I assume that there is a general way to talk about the "transpose" (i.e. the canonical mapping between the space and the dual space) for more general vector spaces, but I don;t know what it is.

Comment: You can take adjoints with respect to nondegenerate quadratic forms. This gives an injection $V\to V^\ast$. This is a generalization of Just a user's answer. And I don't think you can get any more general, because a map $V\to V^\ast$ is equivalent to a map $V\otimes V\to\Bbb F$ by adjunction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be finite dimensional over a field $F$, and $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis of $V$. Then we can define the dual basis $\{e_i^*\}_{i=1}^n$ of $V^*$ such that $e_i^*(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Now for any vector $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$, we can map it to the linear functional $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i^*\in V^*$. This is exactly what the transpose does.

Becasue $$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i^*) (\sum_{i=1}b_i e_i) = \sum_{i, j} a_i e_i^*(b_j e_j) = \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j e_i^*(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i = \begin{pmatrix} a_1, \cdots, a_n \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, I know we can do it for finite dimensional vector spaces, teh question is how to generalize the notation and semantics for it to work on anya rbitrary vector space.

Comment: This is impossible. Because $V$ is not isomorphic to $V^*$ when $\dim V=\infty$. The best one can hope for is when $V$ is equipped with a topology, and $V^*$ consists of only continuous linear functionals. For example, when $V$ is a Hilbert space, then an (almost) isomorhpism between $V$ and $V^*$ is given by Riesz representation, and in terms of notation, physicists use the Dirac bra-ket to identify vectors and covectors.